# How to add library to cross-compile toolchain?

Tags: c++, linux, netbeans, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling

I am using Netbeans to cross-compile C++ code for raspberry pi with arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian. Compiling works fine and I am able to run programs on raspberry but I can't figure out how to add external library files such as RF24 or WiringPi.

According some sources I should create a configure file to install libraries to toolchain but being a newbie to linux, I have no idea how. What should I do?

Comment: Go to Properties -> Linker, click the ... next to additional library directories field to add the directory containing the library  (if necessary) , click the ... next to the Libraries field to add each library.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, that solved one part of the problem. What I needed to do was to install libraries normally to raspberry pi and then copy the just installed library files from pi@:/usr/local/lib to project folder at local computer and then do as you said. Now everything seems to be working.